# Where do the related verse cross references in the CSB Bibles come from?

Tags: bible

Many Bible editions include related verse cross references, which is *separate* from the translator's footnotes, such as this edition of the Christian Standard Bible (CSB) Bible (see [excerpt here](https://www.christianbook.com/Christian/Books/product_slideshow?sku=948685&actual_sku=948685&slide=3) for example).  In that CSB edition, the related verse cross references placed between the two columns while the translator footnotes are on the bottom:

[image: Sample page from CSB Bible with cross reference]

But some CSB editions only include the translator's footnotes, such as the CSB Single-Column Wide-Margin edition (see [excerpt here](https://www.christianbook.com/Christian/Books/product_slideshow?sku=742855&actual_sku=742855&slide=3)).

There is [an answer for a similar question for NIV](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/63804/10672).  Do the CSB Bibles which include verse cross reference uses the same system as the NIV, or a different system?  If different, **which scholars developed the CSB cross reference feature**?

Comment: I take it that CSB relates to the Christian Standart Bible (as per link provided by Mike Borden below).

Comment: @Lesley Yes.  I edited the question with screenshot to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the preface to the 2017 CSB:  https://bibleversion.org/bible/versions/modern-english/christian-standard-bible-holman-csb/christian-standard-bible-preface-2017/

It contains sections on footnotes for OT, NT, and other footnotes as well.  There is a direction to page 27 and an appendix of ancient versions used.  Unfortunately I do not have a paper copy of the CSB and the online versions order the pages differently.

I hope this helps get you started.

Comment: Yes, the preface is a good start, but they don't say who develops the cross reference system, they only say "Cross references are given for parallel passages or passages with similar wording, and in the NT, for passages quoted from the OT."  I also edited the question to clarify that I'm not looking for the footnotes, but the cross reference.